# Count occurrences over a period

Tags: python

If I have a table with a column per day for a whole month with series of 1 and 0, is there a possibility to count how many groupings I have of 1?

With this I mean, if I have `1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1`, is there a way to say in that month I had `4+2+1+3+4+2+1` series of following 1s

And if so, is there a way to complicate it a bit more and count by grouping both 1s and 0s as in 4 ones followed by 2 zeros followed by 2 ones etc.?

Do I make sense?

Comment: I guess, that you want a grouping by week, (and two successive zeroes represent a weekend) for which the starting day of week is missing. But to split the week into two terms just due to a day off in between seems not overly useful.

Comment: Actually is not about weekends.Is just to see the evolution of Out of Stocks in a month, obviously I can easily count how many days a product has been Out of Stock during the month, but it´s interesting to know the cadence. If I have a product that had, let´s say, 5 days Out of Stock in a month, but is one day a week or something like that, customers wont have bother to buy a substitute product, but if it´s 5 following days, then for sure sales will have gone into another product. I´m a forecasting analyst, so this is super important to tweak final demand numbers

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array while tracking previous_character and counter. If the current character is equal to the previous increase the counter, otherwise set previous_character to the current one, and reset the counter to 1.
Every time this reset happens you can print or save in an array a number of connected characters.

Comment: So this would be kinda using a loop like code, no? Do you have in your head how that would look in code? If not I can try to cook my own beans, but if you have already an approximate idea would be absolutely awesome!

Comment: ```char previous_character = array[0];
int counter = 1;
for (int i  = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if(array[i] == previous_character) {
        counter ++;
    } else {
        // print previous_character and counter
       previous_character = array[i];
       counter = 1;
    }
}```

Comment: current_character = array[0]
counter = 1

for i in range(1, len(array)):
    if (array[i] == current_character):
        counter += 1
    else:
        print(current_character + " " + str(counter))
        current_character = array[i]
        counter = 1

Comment: @LazarBojanic You might edit your answer to contain the code supplied in the comment. Code without line structure is always ugly, in Python due to significance of indentation even more so.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
string = '1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1'

num_lst = [int(element) for element in string.split(' ')]

occurrences = 0

prev = 0

occurrences_lst = []

for num in num_lst:
    if num == 1:
        occurrences += 1
    else:
        if occurrences != 0:
            occurrences_lst.append(str(occurrences))
        occurrences = 0

if occurrences == 1:
    occurrences_lst.append(str(occurrences))

print(' + '.join(occurrences_lst))
```

Output:;

```
4 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_character = array[0]
counter = 1

for i in range(1, len(array)):
    if (array[i] == current_character):
        counter += 1
    else:
        print(current_character + " " + str(counter))
        current_character = array[i]
        counter = 1
```

Comment: In Python you don't need to loop over `i in range` - you can iterate directly over the list values like so: `for char in array[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you want to:

1. split your sequence of ones and zeros into subsequences of consecutive ones and consecutive zeros
2. calculate the length of each subsequence

You can use function `groupby` from the `itertools` module to do the splitting:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
output = []
for value, subsequence in groupby(data):
    length = sum(1 for _ in subsequence)
    output.append((value, length))

print(output)
# [(1, 4), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 3), (0, 7), (1, 4), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: You understood correctly, but then probably I need to convert to a usable table format as in to know the distribution of the month and be able to do calculations with that, but probably I´m stepping way ahead (as always) haha, step by step, will apply this solution, and others proposed and then come back for further implementations if required. Million thanks Piotr!